# React native MAX value of number in Textinput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, numbers, textinput

I am creating an input field for numbers in react native. in the text field, we can use the **maxLength** for characters. but I wanna max value of the number in this field.

> for example when I set the limit of number is 10 so the user can't put the 11 of number.

I don't know how to do this. please write your valuable comments or answer. thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `onChangeText` prop you can pass a method just like:

```
  const onCheckLimit = (value: string) => {
    const parsedQty = Number.parseInt(value)
    if (Number.isNaN(parsedQty)) {
      setQuantity(0) //setter for state
    } else if (parsedQty > 10) {
      setQuantity(10)
    } else {
      setQuantity(parsedQty)
    }
  }
/* React Wrapper */
        <Input
          value={quantity}
          onChangeText={onCheckLimit}
          otherProps
        />
/*React Wrapper*/
```

If the value passed is higher than the limit, it will set the value to the limit. Otherwise, simply set the value that the user entered