# React Native: How to enforce max length on input, including after decimal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-textinput

In my React Native app I'm using the `<Input>` component from `Native Base` which is based on the standard `<TextInput>` component. I want to enforce a max length of 5 digits regardless of whether there's a decimal point. So if the user just types 1's, the max would be `11111`, or `111.11`. The problem is that since the input is a string, it considers the decimal point a character, so it stops me after `111.1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could remove the maxLength prop and check the string value yourself in ```onChangeText``` and then update the TextInput value accordingly, perhaps something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/61332316/4340854

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that transforms your number into a string, remove the point and measure the length, then call this function from your onChangeText:

```js
let nrs = [11111, 1111.1, 111.11, 111111, 111.111]

function checkIfLessThenFiveDigits (nr){
 let str = nr.toString() // e.g. "11111", "111.11", "111111"
 let woPoint = str.replace('.', '') // e.g. "11111", "11111", "111111"
 let isValid = woPoint.length <= 5

 return isValid
}

for (var i of nrs)
 console.log(i + ' is ' + checkIfLessThenFiveDigits(i))

// onChangeText={checkIfLessThenFiveDigits}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if your desired max length is, say, 6 numbers, then you'd still momentarily see a 7th number before it gets removed